# Xcode 4 : iOS binary size and strip

Tags: ios, gcc, xcode4, strip

I was trying to minimize the code size in my iOS 4 game, so I tried enabling all the strip-related commands, and using the -Os flag.

However, strangely I still found that the binary was quite big, and when I manually tried to strip the binary using the console ("using the strip command"), it actually reduced it from 18 mb to 12.3 mb.

Does Xcode actually use a different strip mechanism, or anything like that? The problem with using the console strip command is that it gives a message saying that it invalidates the code sign, so I wonder if it's possible to get the code signing working after this strip command.

Comment: If you App is graphics heavy try this tip: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6909772/89035

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you choose "Yes" in **both** "Deployment Postprocessing" and "Strip Linked Product"?

Also, check that you have the right values for the build configuration you try to optimize.

Comment: I did, actually it turns out that I had to clean the whole build directory before it takes effect.. thanks.