# How to analyze ios ipa files info for reduce file size?

Tags: ios, xcode4

I want to reduce compiled file size of ios ipa file.

I get "How to reduce" way: [How to reduce the size of my iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490910/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-my-iphone-application)

But I want to know "How to analyze" way:

My image is

```
$ du /path/to/app
100 /path/to/app/images
150 /path/to/app/sounds
```

And I wan to reduce file size on effective point. Visualization is more good!:
http://www.lomont.org/Software/Utilities/DiskInfo/DiskInfo.png

I know I should delete files which is not used but is linked project...

Answer (score 2):

I have used a tool called [ImageOptim] (http://imageoptim.com/xcode.html)

It incorporates a number of tools inside which crush your png files significantly (in my case it was between 25% to 50%) and had reduced the size of my app of around 0.6 mb

One thing to remember is to disable Xcode's PNG optimization.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic way to reduce the file size of ipa file.

What you can do to reduce the size are just as you said,

- Remove any unnecessary files
- If you have a lot of images, consider using PNGCRUSH to reduce file size of images
- If you have a lot of sound files, consider using compressed audio file such as MP3, also, consider changing to mono instead of stereo. Bit rates of around 96K is still pretty decent.

Comment: When optimizing images you need to [fix Xcode config](http://imageoptim.com/xcode.html), otherwise Xcode will undo the optimizations!