# Decrease iOS Application size to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode5

I am trying to submit an application in App Store, and I need to decrease its memory a little bit, if this is possible. I tried a method which I am gonna describe below to make my app lighter, but with not luck.

## Details

I followed these steps to see what was causing this large size

1. Make an archive of the project
2. Distribute it
3. Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment
4. Select the `.ipa` file and changed the extension to `.zip`
5. Extract it, and open Payload
6. Show the Package Contents

## Contents

I had `.png` files with 680 `Kb` (when I added those where 32 kb approximately), I deleted them and I reduced the size of application by **2 MB**. There are other files that take space but not considerably, except one executable file that is taking about 90 % of the `.ipa's` size.

## Question

Is it possible to decrease executable file's size? If not then can you give me a hint where I should look to make my app lighter in terms of size.

*P.S I use third party libraries like [Vuforia SDK](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/ios) and libraries on **GitHUB***

Comment: Why do you think it's "too big" ?

Comment: @runmad Because, I have a kind of program that does not approach to the complexity of an application of 30 Mb. Images I think are not an issue, so the code is not so big either. Read the question fully

Comment: I did, just not sure why you're concerned with the app size being 28 MB. See answer below.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why is this post closing. At least describe the details why, so I could improve it.

Comment: Retina images bloat an application extremely quickly.  Open up the .app and look and see how big various things are and see what you think you can shrink.  One option is to eliminate most/all non-retina artwork as the system will gladly use the retina images and scale them for you.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I reduce the size of this **executable file**

You cannot reduce the size of the executable inside your built app bundle. This is your code! The only ways to reduce its size are:

- Cut code. Obviously you can't do that because you would exclude functionality that makes your app work.
- Remove an architecture slice. You should not do that because you want to build for all possible architectures.

Having said that... I have *never* generated an executable inside the app bundle anywhere near this large. Maybe you are measuring / building wrong:

- Make sure you are archiving. Nothing else except an archive is worth measuring.
- Make sure that you are generating a Release build when you Archive.
- Make sure that your Release build settings include the full compiler optimization (smallest, fastest).

Comment: Yes there are small, and fastest, I have tried also archiving and release. I tried out too many posts related to this issue. But thnx for pointing me out how to reduce the executable file size. Now suppose if I have some classes that I don't use in this project but are added at the compile sources, do they raise the size of the project?

Comment: Yes; some compilers / languages have magical "code stripping" where unused code is removed, but I don't think Clang gives you anything like that. Nevertheless, 30MB of compiled code, if it is your compiled code that takes up the space, would be a heck of a LOT of code.

Comment: Note that you can readily see (and control) what goes into the executable by looking at the target's Build Phases.

Comment: Yes I am checking that out. In fact about libraries I am using Vuforia which is implemented on OpenGL and Unity3D and it has some code in it. I'll give it a try tomorrow :)

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion how to reduce binary size from [Reducing the size of my App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html):

> **Compiler Options**
>
> Setting the Optimization Level build setting to Fastest, Smallest [-Os]; and the Strip Debug Symbols During Copy build setting to Yes (COPY_PHASE_STRIP = YES) can dramatically lower the size of your compiled binary. These settings are the default for the "Release" configuration in Xcode projects.

Answer (score 1):

Assets are almost always the main culprit of large apps sizes.

If you archive your app and export the IPA you will be able to convert it so a .zip by changing the extension and then unzip and look at the contents of the package.

If you sort by file size you will see which files are the largest. Keep in mind images with transparency are larger.

Some more insight as well: http://bjango.com/articles/pngcompression/

Comment: Yes but at the question I have specified that I have done this, and the troubled images with large memory have been deleted. So this is not something that is causing trouble I think. The problem is with the executable file

Comment: You should still be able to see what's taking up so much space. What about 3rd party library bundles?

Comment: How to check 3rd party libraries?

Answer (score 1):

If you're truly concerned about the internals of the executable, build with a link map.  That shows sizes by segment and by symbol.

e.g.

```
# Sections:
# Address   Size        Segment Section
0x0000AB90  0x00711D30  __TEXT  __text
0x0071C8C0  0x00028D34  __TEXT  __symbol_stub4
0x007455F4  0x00001A58  __TEXT  __stub_helper
0x0074704C  0x00057452  __TEXT  __cstring
```

[…]

```
# Symbols:
# Address   Size        File  Name
0x000122A0  0x00000020  [  6] ___Block_byref_object_copy_
0x000122C0  0x0000001C  [  6] ___Block_byref_object_dispose_
0x00012320  0x00000028  [  6] ___copy_helper_block_78
0x00012348  0x0000001C  [  6] ___destroy_helper_block_79
```

[…]

Comment: What can I achieve by doing this? Maybe I am new to iOS development and that's why I find it difficult to track the project with this. What command should I do or how to do this link map? Thnx for your time

Comment: In Xcode's build settings, there's an option called "Write Link Map File" that's either Yes or No.  What you achieve is knowing what part of your application is large and therefore what part might get you the most payback if you were to optimize it.  (OTOH, maybe I should ask what kind of things you're willing to consider as ways to make the app smaller…if you're new to development, it may not be an easy chore.)

Answer (score 1):

I came across an [article](https://pimdewitte.me/2016/11/03/optimizing-ios-builds-in-unity-a-tutorial-for-getting-under-the-100mb-over-the-air-download-limit-on-the-app-store/) in the web which explains the process in the following 9 points:

> 1. Ensure that you have reached the maximum level of iOS stripping, for
>      more info on iOS stripping, see this post.
> 2. Enabling bitcode DOES increase the size of your over-the-air download.
>      In our case, it was the difference between 130 and 70MB. If you wish
>      to turn bitcode off, you can do so in your xcode project, or using a
>      post build attribute such as this one.
> 3. The Launch image in your xcode project is NOT optimized. While running
>      something through a compression algorithm doesn’t work because Unity
>      decompresses and stores images without much compression in order to
>      decrease startup time, it does work for the launch images that are
>      generated by Untiy after project generation.Run all your images
>      through a lossless compression algorithm in order to save a few MBs
>      (10 in our case).
> 4. If this isn’t enough, it’s time to start looking at your asset logs.
>      Run your build in Unity and open the Editor log, it’s this
>      ridiculously small icon next to your console preferences. In our case,
>      they are already optimized. With a 111MB in uncompressed assets, we
>      were able to achieve an over-the-air size of 70MB. Go over each asset
>      and change the resolution to the lowest possible quality that your
>      users won’t notice. The best compression setting is PVRTC for iOS.
>      While you are at it, check out Resource Checker in order to see large
>      textures in-memory. Reducing the resolution on these will also
>      decrease build size, as well as memory consumption. Also, please use
>      sprite atlases – you will see the wonders this does!
> 5. Check for unused libraries in your project, or libraries that are
>      using far too much space for their functionality. Commands such as df
>      and ls -lh might come in useful here, run these in your project files
>      and see which files really stand out and need to be reduced in size.
>      Keep in mind that these individual libraries do not necessarily have
>      the same build effect as your textures – generally, these are compiled
>      for multiple architectures, and if a library is 20MB, it generally
>      only affects your build size by about 6MB, due to the fact that
>      libraries often include architecture support for i386, arm64, and arm7
>      in the same library
> 6. Check that the /Plugins/Android is not included in your iOS project.
>      See this post for more information.
> 7. Make sure you don’t have any unused scenes in your build settings.
> 8. Build your project, and check out the archive before you submit it to
>      iTunes Connect. You can do so by clicking “Product -> Archive”,
>      letting it archive, and when it’s done, “Window -> Organizer” to pop
>      up this interface and find the build location.
>
>    Under “Products/Applications/game.app” Run the mv command to turn your
>      .app into a browsable directory.In this directory you’ll be able to
>      see a lot of the stuff we did, and also find inspiration for more
>      things you can do.
>
> Now, there are a lot more things that could result in a bigger than
>   expected build size, and I’m sure there are a lot more things you can
>   to do get below it also.

If you’d like to add to this list, or have further questions (I’m usually happy to answer questions), leave a comment below with your specific use case, and I’ll try to help!

All the best,

Pim

Comment: Do not add link only answers under any circumstances. While they may theoretically answer the question, [it is always be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Alternatively, you ca always leave them as comments from which the OP (and others) can take help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already checked all your assets (images, audio, etc... ) just check if you need all the external libraries (3rd party libraries out of the iOS sdk) that you import in your app.

Comment: How to check them. I mean I know I have imported libraries so what should I do?

Comment: "external libraries and frameworks" are not part of the ipa and do not contribute to the IPA size.

Comment: If they're 3rd party libraries they will.

Comment: Look I have updated the question, I meant I reduced the size by 2 Mb not to 2 Mb. My size of the app is 30 Mb

Comment: I was refering to libraries out of the iOS sdk, that contribute to the IPA size. I've edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: If he says that has checked all his assets, this is the only other place to reduce the size.

Comment: @gabuh where can I find those third party libraries?

Comment: If you are using Vuforia and Unity, as I think you said in a previous post, it comes with a big bunch of code. Maybe you could strip some parts to reduce the exec size.. but I can't help you with that. Good luck.