# How to reduce the size of .ipa file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift2, ipa

I have developed iOS app using swift language.

While generating ipa i selected Save for Adhoc distribution, the ipa size is 7mb.

Now i want to move appstore, so i selected Save for iOS app store deployment, then ipa size is 50mb.

Source code size is 11mb.

Why it is that much difference, Please suggest me.

Comment: Can you specify a bit more about the contents of your project? Apple already crushes PNGs. You might still want to crush them yourself too might they be the factor of the app bloating. Also, looking at your profile; is your app build in Cordova? It might cause bloating to your project. Not sure in what way, but apps I deploy hardly ever exceed 3MB. Of course this is also strongly based on how much data is loaded externally and what is deployed with the app itself. My smallest app ironically has the biggest code-base (thousands of lines of code) and media but only compiling to a 1.1MB IPA file.

Comment: My app is developed using swift not cordova, if i select adhoc distribution while creating .ipa file size is 7mb. If i select appstore distribution option size is more around 48mb is coming

Comment: I deploy some apps to both Enterprise and the live store too with almost no bytes in difference. Can you still please elaborate your content. Also you might use different build targets, causing unnecessary files to be included in your build. If you don't elaborate more details specifically to your projects internals you might risk getting the issue closed. Simply trying to help :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938500/decrease-ios-application-size-to-app-store[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938500/decrease-ios-application-size-to-app-store)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321409/reducing-ios-app-file-size[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321409/reducing-ios-app-file-size)
[https://imageoptim.com/xcode.html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490910/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-my-iphone-application)

Comment: My source code memory also 11mb only, if i generate ipa its giving 50 mb

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, after deploying the app into Appstore, build came to 8Mb, i think its apple issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With the advent of bit code and app thinning, it's more complex to figure out the size of your app that the user will actually download.

You should make sure you are set up to support BitCode and app thinning. Those things will make the IPA file you submit to the app store **larger**, but the actual IPA that's delivered to the user **smaller**.

(BitCode uploads an intermediate binary representation of your app's code to the app store, which the app store then compiles for the target device, rather than including a "fat" binary that has separate executables for each target processor.

App thinning causes the system to split out the platform-specific and resolution-specific assets (e.g. non-retina, @2x, and @3x artwork, plus iPad and iPhone specific full-screen images, storyboards, etc.) and only deliver the assets for the user's particular device.)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, after deploying the app into App store, build came to 8Mb, i think its apple issue.

Comment: @laxman, it's not an issue. And this is well explained by Duncan. Please accept the answer if it has helped you and you think is appropriate for your question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Following solution for hermes enabled and RN 0.64.2**

1. Need to do bitcode enabled - Yes at Build setting tab in xcode.
2. Need to choose deployment target version above ios 13.1.
3. Then once do clean & build and then archive. your .ipa file size will be reduce.

Answer (score 0):

Code coverage/ Instrument flow tracking turned off in Xcode build settings.