# .ipa have a large size how to reduce it in React Native?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I have a small project written in React Native CLI, After Archive it and export the .ipa file I got a large size it's 172MB!!

[image]

I have enabled Bitcode in release mode,
And disable all Flipper stuff but the size still the same (large)

How can I reduce it?

Note
I don't have any assets like fonts big images, just a splash screen image (4kb)

Comment: Here is solution for above issue :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68661895/8900599

Answer (score 0):

IPAs are ZIP files. In your IPA file, replace .ipa to .zip, expand it, right click on the .app file and click Show Contents. There you can see what parts of the app are what's causing it to be so big.

If I had to guess, though, the binary is really big because it's bundling the whole react native runtime. There's no a lot you can do about this.

If you're building with a Debug configuration, changing it to Release will strip debug symbols and make your binary smaller.

Comment: I have a package named react-native-geolocation-service
it's required to add swift file and the bridging header
so after deleting the package and related stuff (swift & bridging files) I got this size ( from 172 to 61 MB) 