# ".ipa" file size issues -xcode archive

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, itunes

I have created an project of size nearly 5 MB, but after archiving app from xworkspace it increases upto 194Mb and IPA file size upto 70 MB.

Will it fine to have a large size "ipa" for normal application ?

Thank you

Comment: not use test certificate and provision profile use client or account specific app certificate

Comment: Maybe this could help (also it's a bit aged) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490910/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-my-iphone-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your entire project is only 5Mb size, you may have a dependency or copy build path resources problem.

Double check :

- do you need all frameworks linked to the project ?
- do you have a build phase which copy to final resources path unused or unwanted files ?
- if you use dependency manager suche as `cocoapod` or `carthage`: are all the pulled external frameworks necessary ?

If you want to know what are the big files, it's pretty easy once you have the IPA file: rename your ipa with "zip" extension, unarchive, explore

Bonus: Even the finder say to you "XX MB", it's not the final size. To know the final size, you can upload your ipa on ituneconnect, even if you don't want to use it. after processing, in builds list. You can have the final size for each devices. ex:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi0HZ.png]

As you can see `Universal` is quite big compared to the specific build for, for ex, iphone 6 !

Comment: Thank you. yes  i have checked it out project for larger files. i didn't find any particular larger file . There were all necessary dependencies i had included.

Comment: You may have bitcode set to enable... and other thing is dSYM file.To disable then SET Bitcode to NO & Dsym release mode to DWARF.

Comment: @Nitesh IPA files does not include DSYM (it's for .xcarchive), but yes bitcode can enlarge file size, even though, with iOS 11 incoming, it's a good idea to let bitcode setted to true (Apple will recompile it for you)

Comment: @jlngdt Thanks! But when I export .IPA file It gives 2 checkmarks one with dSYm and other with Bitcode. Please explain I'm new...have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440520/mobile-app-size-on-apple-app-store-with-bitcode-enabled

Comment: @jlngdt So now App Store not take 163 MB as cellular download limits & shows 40 MB to user ?

Answer (score 2):

It is fine as long as the IPA file size is less than 100 MB. Once the file size becomes larger than 100MB, then it won't be available to download from the Appstore on Cellular Internet. It will be available to download only on WiFi.

I would recommend you inspect the Xcode project to find large dependencies that are causing the file size to increase.

Comment: Edit, with iOS 11, the limit has been updated: 150 MB